# when i upload file i am getting "folder" value null

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have go through a code to upload a file in in our local system. i got folder value null, and after uploading file where it stored why i have refered it at location `Liferay/tomcat/Root/webapps/My portletname/` with a null folder? 
my view.jsp is here.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui"%>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil"%>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator"%>
 <%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences"%>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.util.PwdGenerator"%>
 <portlet:defineObjects />
<%
String uploadProgressId = PwdGenerator.getPassword(PwdGenerator.KEY3, 4);
    PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();

%>

<portlet:actionURL var="editCaseURL" name="uploadCase">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<liferay-ui:error key="error"
   message="Sorry, an error prevented the upload. Please try again." />
<liferay-ui:upload-progress
    id="<%= uploadProgressId %>"
    message="uploading"
    redirect="<%= editCaseURL %>"
  />

<aui:form action="<%= editCaseURL %>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
<select>
  <option value="store">Store</option>
  <option value="floor">Floor</option>
  <option value="department">Department</option>
</select> 
<aui:input type="file" name="fileName" size="75"/>
<input type="submit" value="<liferay-ui:message key="upload" />" onClick="<%= uploadProgressId %>.startProgress(); return true;"/>
<!--  aui:button type="submit" value="Save" /-->
</aui:form>

<br />
<portlet:renderURL var="viewCaseURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/view2.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<aui:button onClick="<%=viewCaseURL%>" value="view Uploaded Doc" />
```

my controller is here:

```
package com.upload.doc;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionMessages;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.upload.UploadPortletRequest;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;


  public class DocUpload extends MVCPortlet {
            public void uploadCase(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionRresponse) throws PortletException,IOException {

                   String folder = getInitParameter("uploadFolder");

                   String realPath = getPortletContext().getRealPath("/");

                   System.out.println("RealPath" + realPath +"\\" + folder);
try {

UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
System.out.println("Size: "+uploadRequest.getSize("fileName"));

if (uploadRequest.getSize("fileName")==0) {SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "error");}

String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName");
File file = uploadRequest.getFile("fileName");

System.out.println("Name file:" + uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName"));
File newFolder = null;
newFolder = new File(realPath +"\\" + folder);
if(!newFolder.exists()){
newFolder.mkdir();
}
             File newfile = null;
               newfile = new File(newFolder.getAbsoluteFile()+"\\"+sourceFileName);
               System.out.println("New file name: " + newfile.getName());
               System.out.println("New file path: " + newfile.getPath());

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uploadRequest.getFileAsStream("fileName"));
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newfile);

            byte[] bytes_ = FileUtil.getBytes(in);
            int i = fis.read(bytes_);

               while (i != -1) {
               fos.write(bytes_, 0, i);
               i = fis.read(bytes_);
            }
    fis.close();
    fos.close();
          Float size = (float) newfile.length();
          System.out.println("file size bytes:" + size);
          System.out.println("file size Mb:" + size / 1048576);

          System.out.println("File created: " + newfile.getName());
          SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "success");

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "error");
                         } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        System.out.println("File Not Found");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "error");
                        }

                    catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
                    SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "error");

e1.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

and my portlet.xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>docupload</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Docupload</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.upload.doc.DocUpload</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/view.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Docupload</title>
            <short-title>Docupload</short-title>
            <keywords>Docupload</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

Comment: crossreferencing https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/54565674

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your question by not answering it, but by pointing out the underlying design mistake that you have made:

It's best practice to *not* upload anything to your webapplication's folder. This is for a variety of reasons:

- You'll never be able to know what exactly is deployed
- Disaster recovery is harder when the application changes constantly
- You can configure the application server to not even serve files from a filesystem, but just from a zipped war file
- It's best practice to have the webapp write-protected for the appserver, this way nobody can attack the server by uploading arbitrary content to your webapplication
- Assume somebody uploads `fileexplorer.jsp` to your appserver and then accesses the file through the browser. Alternatively, that someone injects a `/WEB-INF/lib/attacking-code.jar`

All these reasons lead me to suggest that you are not looking for a solution to the problem that you're stating. You have an underlying problem that you want to solve.

Find a place to store your data, outside of your application server. Redesign your application to not rely on uploaded files in its own webcontext. Maybe the stated upload problems just disappear then. If not, ask again, then with the new context.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, as you listed lot of drawback of that, and it is the real concern for me as well. I can change the property to upload file through liferay-ext.properties. But it will upload all the files there uploaded by entire liferay instance,  i am looking for the answer how can i do that for the single stand portlet.

Comment: did you mean uploading to your portlet's directory instead of to Liferay's? If so: That doesn't make a difference. Otherwise: I don't understand what you want otherwise. There's a myriad of articles that you can find for how to implement a file upload portlet. I might have voted to close a few as duplicates on stackoverflow alone but they are literally everywhere. Just *don't* upload to an application directory that's deployed to a webserver. Don't, Don't, Don't!

Comment: I am not going to do that, as you can see `getPortletContext().getRealPath` is uploading file in liferay's temp folder, but i want it to upload it my custom `/home/mydirectory` location.

Comment: note that getRealPath("/") results in a directory inside tomcat/webapps, which you can call anything *but* a temp folder. Anyway - I hope to have given you some reasons to not upload there. If your new request is "Show me how to upload a file" please update your question and be prepared for it to be closed as duplicate. *That* question has been answered numerous times. I specifically stated that I will not answer the question as you have currently asked it, rather tell you why you don't want to implement it the way you describe in your question. I'm now totally confused about your intent